# As he's gone/left

Tags: grammar

Ben enters the restroom, checks for feet under the stalls, then heads back out. As he's gone, a pair of feet appears in a stall and Greg comes out of his hide.

Questions to this:

1. Is "checks for feet under the stalls" okay? Or should it be "stall doors"?
2. Is "as he's gone" grammatically correct? Or should it be "as he's left"?

Comment: ***while** he's gone*. There's no good way to handle the plurality of "a pair of feet" here - regardless of whether you use singular ***appears*** or plural ***appear***, at least *some* people won't like your choice.

Comment: With "as" I mean "when". And with "he's" I mean "he has". Is "As he's gone" not correct?

Comment: In this context, ***when*** and ***while*** are equivalent (as distinct from the alternative reading ***as = since , because,*** which isn't what you intend to say). But as regards whether ***he's*** stands for ***is*** or ***has***, I think the vast majority of native speakers would say it's *While he **is** gone,* (though ***has*** is also syntactically valid; it's just not very idiomatic).

Comment: "Greg comes out of his hide" also sounds weird. Maybe "Greg comes out of his hiding place"

Answer (score 1):

1. A "stall" is the booth itself, not the door to the stall.  So I'd suggest it should be "stall doors".
2. I prefer "once he's gone" (which would suggest Ben's left the restroom and is moving down the hall (or wherever)) or "as he leaves" (which suggests the feet appear just as Ben is passing back into the hall (or wherever) from the restroom).  But also, feet wouldn't appear in a stall, unless they're some sort of magic item...I think that needs a re-word - maybe "a pair of feet become visible under the stall door" - I think it depends from what angle you want the reader to visualise what's going on.  Also, I think "a pair of feet appear" sounds better than "a pair of feet appears" - that doesn't appear to be correct to me.

Comment: I'll have to disagree with you on the 'appeared'. While it isn't dictionary, it is the kind of thing that would be used in fiction. "Right after Sue got undressed, Jack appeared in the doorway." The idea being that Sue didn't even know Jack was in the house, so his 'coming to the doorway and looking in' was such a surprise that it seemed to her as if he magically 'appeared'.

Answer (score 1):

1. The option "stall doors" is correct here. The "stalls" in a restroom are themselves the small rooms with toilets.
2. The word "as" can be used to link two verbs happening concurrently, like "when" or "while", but this pattern is used for verbs in the continuous aspect ("he leaves/goes"), not the perfect aspect ("he's gone"):

   - "As *he sank* into the bath, he thought about his day."
   - "As *I eat* my sandwich, Susan plays the piano."
   - "You will notice many beautiful buildings as *you drive* down Main Street."

In this case, you might use the present continuous "as he leaves" or "as he goes". If you mean that the feet appear *after* Ben leaves the restroom, then another phrase would be more appropriate: "As soon as he leaves", "after he's gone", etc.

Answer (score 1):

***"Ben enters the restroom, checks for feet under the stalls, then heads back out. As he's gone, a pair of feet appears in a stall and Greg comes out of his hide."***

**1. Is "checks for feet under the stalls" okay? Or should it be "stall doors"?**

"Stalls" is fine. Maybe "stall doors" is more precise, but I didn't have an issue with it saying just "stalls" when I first read it, fully comprehending the meaning without giving it a second thought. In fact, except that you brought it up, I wouldn't consider it an issue at all, mostly because it's not. Here are some citations from published novels just in 2019 alone in which the author used the exact phrase "I checked under the stalls":

> "Then the group bolted thru the door. I checked under the stalls, no
> feet. Then I began opening doors on the stalls, voila!" -Karen
> A. Bowen, *[One Conscious Choice](https://books.google.com/books?id=LSrJDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT92&dq=%22checked%20under%20the%20stalls%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiw2_7V7szwAhWXZ80KHY4NAM8Q6AEwAHoECAQQAg)* (2019)
>
> "She went into the restroom, checked under the stalls, and dialed his
> number.:" -Cheyenne McCray, *[Dark Seduction](https://books.google.com/books?id=9f6fDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT77&dq=%22checked%20under%20the%20stalls%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiw2_7V7szwAhWXZ80KHY4NAM8Q6AEwAXoECAAQAg)* (2019)
>
> "He stood before it for a few seconds and then checked under the
> stalls to make sure no one else was in the bathroom." -Josh Allen,
> *[Out to Get You](https://books.google.com/books?id=dH7RDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT103&dq=%22checked%20under%20the%20stalls%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiw2_7V7szwAhWXZ80KHY4NAM8Q6AEwAnoECAMQAg)* (2019)

For myriad more examples from myriad other years that provide foundation that "I checked under the stalls" is perfectly acceptable to mean what you mean, check [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=checked%20under%20the%20stalls&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchecked%20under%20the%20stalls%3B%2Cc0).

But, sure, if you want to say "stall doors," say "stall doors." It's a free country.

**2. Is "as he's gone" grammatically correct? Or should it be "as he's left"?**

I'm puzzled by some answers and comments posted here in regard to this second question. "[As](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/as)" in that context clearly means "since; because" (see def. 8 - https://www.dictionary.com/browse/as). Saying "as" there is perfectly grammatical, natural, and fine.

***By the way***, I did do a doubletake on "[hide](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/hide)" in the second sentence, but I looked it up and it turns out that while "hide" isn't a noun in American English, which is what I speak, in British English, it is and means "a camouflaged shelter used to get a close view of wildlife." That certainly could have figurative applications, most especially in the context of a public restroom stall and using it as camouflaged shelter to get a close view of that public restroom's "wildlife," *though I'd watch out for coppers, mate, or you're well likely to get nicked.*